# In c# is it possible to dump all the local varialbles within that scope where an exception in generated?

Tags: c#, debugging, logging

Is there any way to dump all the local variables to log with in the scope of try catch block where an exception in generated before it goes to the catch block or with in the catch block.

For example:

```
void Demo() 
{
    try
    {
        int a = 20;
        int b = 20;
        string c = "Hello";
        int d = 1 / (a-b);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Here divide by zero exception is generated, and I want to dump the values of a,b,c and d variables. The linked question does not resolve the problem.

Comment: It'd come at a high cost, if you expect it to happen in your released code - the optimizer can make a fair few decisions based upon the known lifetimes of locals and having to prolong all of those lifetimes to a later part of the method, just in case an exception is thrown, may defeat optimization.

Comment: Need to track the problem it is comming in some specific situation.

Comment: When you feel that it is necessary that all variable values are tracked that is more an indicator of poor code quality. Probably the method is doing to much and should be split into multiple smaller methods.

Comment: You should probably include the *relevant* parameters in the exception, either as fields, or in the message itself. If `a` and `b` where parameters to a method you should check these parameters at the start, and throw an exception if they are invalid.